# How to show Fixture on Google search result

Tags: google, google-search

I was searching for some football match fixture when i saw google showing fixtures right on the search result.

[image]

That makes me wondering if there is some technology I am missing (like microformat for showing user reviews)

**Same goes for event listings.**

[image]

So, **what technology they used for this or its just google organic pickup?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

schema.org has microformats for almost anything you can think of including sports events and events in general. Keep in mind that using them doesn't guarantee that Google will display results like you see above. In fact they typically reserve verbose listings like that for the first results in rankings for very popular search terms.

Comment: Thanks! I see the event and whole lots of formats there.